# trace inequality for Dirichlet Neumann operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Does there exists a Sobolev trace inequality of the form

$$ \|U(x, 0)\|_{L^{q}((a, b))} \leq C\sqrt{q}\| \nabla  U \|_{L^{2} (\mathcal C)} ; \forall U\in H^{1}_{0, L} (\mathcal C)$$ and for any $q>1$ 
where $H^{1}_{0,L} (\mathcal C)= \{U \in H^{1}(\mathcal C): U(a, t)= U(b, t)=0  \}$; $\mathcal C=(a, b)\times(0, \infty).$  Here $C>0$ is independent of $U$ and $q.$

Comment: I think yes. Expand $U(x,t)=\sum_k c_k(t)\sin kx$ (assuming $a=0,b=\pi$, figure out the $L^2$ norm of the gradient, estimate $c_k(0)$ from there (I got $c_k(0)=\frac {s_k}{\sqrt k}$ where $s_k$ can be an arbitrary $\ell^2$ sequence whose norm is bounded by $\|\nabla U\|_{L^2(C)}$), and use Hausdorff-Young and Holder after that.

Comment: Thank you. But not sure if the proof goes through for all q>1.

Comment: Why? Where do you have trouble? It works for $q>2$, of course, but other norms are just smaller.